# How can I css only one of my webpages?

Tags: css, styles

I have read answers on this topic here in stackoverflow, however I couldn't do it. I am creating a website. In one page I need the style to be like this:

```
body{
   line-height: 18px;  
   margin-top: 100px; 
}
```

however I need one webpage (alias:blog) to have no margin.

Comment: How do you differentiate each page? Is there a class? You could try adding a class on the body tag for that particular page.

Comment: You can do it with javascript using a conditional statement, or you can give the body a class for that specific page and apply the CSS to the class.

Answer (score 3):

Bro, you can link different stylesheets per page. 
For example:

Page with margin:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="first.css">
```

Blog:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blog.css">
```

Or you can add a class to your body like this:

Page without margin (HTML)

```
<body class="no-margin"></body>
```

Then your CSS would look like this:

```
body{
   line-height: 18px;  
   margin-top: 100px; 
}
body.no-margin{
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes or you could add inline style in your body tag, if this is a one off. e.g:

```
<body style="line-height:18px; margin-top: 100px;">
```

Other methods people have mentioned are also valid.